# Check if a String matches specific regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I am not so good with regular expressions and stuff, so I need help. I have to check if a input value matches a specific regular expression format. Here is the format I want to use, `25D8H15M`. Here the `D` means the # of days `H` means hours and `M` means minutes. I need the regular expression to check the String. Thanks

Comment: @Bohemian, what I need to do is: check if the given string is valid, valid values are: 1D - 2D15H - 5H33M - 22D30M - 15D12H45M etc.

Comment: So all parts are optional, but there must be at least one part? Is `3D5M` valid? Is there a maximum number value for the days part?

Comment: @Bohemian no there is not maximum for the days part

Comment: OK - see my updated answer that meets your extended requirements

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the briefest way to code the regex:

```
if (str.matches("(?!$)(\\d+D)?(\\d\\d?H)?(\\d\\d?M)?"))
    // format is correct
```

This allows each part to be optional, but the negative look ahead for end-of-input at the start means there must be *something* there.

Note how with java you don't have to code the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of input, because `String.matches()` must match the *whole* string, so start and end are *implied*.

However, this is just a rudimentary regex, because `99D99H99M` will pass. The regex for a *valid* format would be:

```
if (str.matches("(?!$)(\\d+D)?([0-5]?\\dH)?([0-5]?\\dM)?"))
    // format is correct
```

This restricts the hours and minutes to `0-59`, allowing an optional leading zero for values in the range `0-9`.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified regex can be:

```
^\\d{1,2}D\\d{1,2}H\\d{1,2}M$
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava for the answer, I have a question though, what does the numbers in the curly brackets mean?

Comment: `\\d{1,2}` means match 1 or 2 digits these numbers mean lower limit and upper limit of # of matched patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
    String regex = "\\d{1,2}D\\d{1,2}H\\d{1,2}M";
    String str = "25D8H15M";

    System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

Comment: It will also match `111125D8H15MMMM`

Comment: @anubhava, nope, I have just tested.

Comment: `String#matches` adds `^ and $` but if same regex is used in Pattern then it will match bigger string.

Comment: @anubhava with java you don't have to code the start (^) and end ($) of input, because `String.matches()` must match the *whole* string, so start and end are implied

Comment: @Masud the character classes are unnecessary here, ie `\\d{1,2}` is identical to `[\\d]{1,2}` because there's only one character (type)

Comment: @Bohemian: That is what I had written in my comment that `String#matches adds ^ and $` but if this regex is used in `Pattern/Matcher` with `Matcher#find` then it is different thing.